# DLL iOS Xamarin project doesn't build without any error in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, dll

Here is the log

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OxyPlot.Xamarin.iOS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored D:\...\MyApp\MyApp\Autofac\Autofac.csproj (in 108 ms).
1>  Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Remote Server. 
1>              Properties: 
1>                  SessionId=b2c2c29378abf7c944566f76ca68a6dc43fad4b8538dd7c4bd39fd2d30164eb5, 
1>                  Addresss=192.168.10.224, 
1>                  SshPort=22, 
1>                  TcpPort=57058, 
1>                  User=dims, 
1>                  AppName=OxyPlot.Xamarin.iOS,
1>                  VisualStudioProcessId=2364,
1>                  ContinueOnDisconnected=False
2>D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\PlotView.cs(42,25,42,34): warning CS0618: 'Device.OS' is obsolete: 'TargetPlatform is obsolete as of version 2.3.4. Please use RuntimePlatform instead.'
2>D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\PlotView.cs(44,26,44,40): warning CS0612: 'TargetPlatform' is obsolete
2>D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\PlotView.cs(48,26,48,40): warning CS0612: 'TargetPlatform' is obsolete
2>D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\PlotView.cs(52,26,52,40): warning CS0612: 'TargetPlatform' is obsolete
2>D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\PlotView.cs(56,26,56,40): warning CS0612: 'TargetPlatform' is obsolete
2>  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms -> D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms\bin\Debug\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.dll
1>  OxyPlot.Xamarin.iOS -> D:\...\MyApp\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.iOS\bin\Debug\OxyPlot.Xamarin.iOS.dll
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

First DLL is created, second one is not. Failed counts confirms this, but no any error reported.

How to investigate?

Comment: increase the verbosity level for the build log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Diagnostic MSBuild** can contain additional information relating to package building and may contain some package deployment information.

To enable diagnostic MSBuild output within Visual Studio:

**Click Tools > Options...**
In the left-hand tree view, select **Projects and Solutions** > **Build and Run**
In the right-hand panel, set the MSBuild build output verbosity dropdown to **Diagnostic**
Click OK
Clean and rebuild your package.
Diagnostic output is visible within the Output panel.
To enable diagnostic MSBuild output within Visual Studio for Mac/OS X:

Click Visual Studio for Mac > Preferences...
In the left-hand tree view, select Projects > Build
In the right-hand panel, set the Log verbosity drop-down to Diagnostic
Click OK
Restart Visual Studio for Mac
Clean and rebuild your package.
Diagnostic output is visible within the Errors Pad (View > Pads > Errors ), by clicking the Build Output button.